# Project works in Visual Studio. But vscode + Omnisharp fails with "You need to specify platform (x86, Win32 or x64)" for Nuget pkg: ScreenRecorderLib

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

I have C# .Net Framework Winforms project that I've created in Visual Studio.  In Visual Studio, everything is fine, it compiles, debugs, runs etc.

But when I try to work on my project in vscode with the Omnisharp extension, Omnisharp can't even parse my project, it fails with error:

```
...\packages\ScreenRecorderLib.3.1.2\build\ScreenRecorderLib.targets(6,5): Error: ScreenRecorderLib does not work correctly on 'AnyCPU' platform. You need to specify platform (x86, Win32 or x64).
```

---

- **Question #1: Why is this only a problem for vscode/Omnisharp, when everything is fine in Visual Studio?**

---

- **Question #2: How do I solve this?**

I've tried looking at the project properties in Visual Studio, and I have everything set to x64 already as far as I can find for my project (see screenshot below).  Although the error is about the Nuget package I'm using: ScreenRecorderLib... So is this even something I can fix within my own project files?

[image: Project CPU properties]

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here. I am avoiding this issue by editing ScreenRecorderLib.targets file which is under C:\Users\<username>\.nuget\packages\screenrecorderlib\3.1.2\build folder.

My final file is like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">


  <Target Name="InjectReference" BeforeTargets="ResolveAssemblyReferences">
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="ScreenRecorderLib">
      <HintPath>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)x64\ScreenRecorderLib.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

As you may notice, I am "forcing" in some way to use x64 dll because it is what I need. I cannot consider this as a solution to the problem but at least I can skip this issue and continue.